# Local MAMP server is working on my Mac. Is there a way to access its files from my Linux machine?

Tags: linux, macos, server, mamp

A complete novice with MAMP, I can now type localhost:8888/JW/ClimateChange.shtml into a browser on my Mac and see the relevant file with CSS and SSI working as they should. This is a big step forward, but I was hoping that MAMP would let a colleague on another continent see my work also. Is there a way to do this short of buying a domain name? Reading related answers leaves me confused, perhaps because I am barely literate in Unix, and not at all in PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that one of the following is true:

- The machines are on the same local network
- The machines are effectively on the same local network via a VPN
- The server is directly facing the public Internet
- The router that connects the server's network to the public Internet is configured to use port forwarding to forward requests to a specific port to the server's port 8888
- A tool such as SSH is used to create port forwarding over an encrypted tunnel (requires a public facing SSH server)

Then replace `localhost` with the IP address of the server (or the router if you use the port forwarding approach)